# What are some IP based protocols that don't use ports like TCP or UDP do?

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcp

I'm learning about the Internet Protocol (IP) often referred to as TCP/IP. From what I understand, the Transport Control Protocol (TCP) is actually a totally different thing than IP. It's a layer on top of IP that does some more data integrity control. And, from what I understand, what is referred to as "ports", for example "port 80" for the HTTP protocol, is a TCP thing, not an IP thing.

**So, what protocols that use the Internet Protocol under the hood don't use the notion of ports?**

If you can link to open source software that implements such a protocol, that would be great.

Comment: Alright, thanks. You know, that is not obvious to everybody ;-)

Comment: It would be more to the point to list the protocols that *do* use ports, and I believe you've already done that: TCP and UDP. Also SCTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco has a list of protocols their routers support that are on top of IP with no TCP necessary.  These are usually not supported directly by hosts, and are usually used by the infrastructure for network maintenance ...

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/cable/serv_exch/serv_control/broadband_app/apa/2-0-0/user/guide/APADC_UG/Protocols.html#wp1075138

```
HOPOPT
ICMP
IGMP
GGP
IP
ST
CBT
EGP
IGP
BBN-RCC-MON
NVP-II
PUP
ARGUS
EMCON
XNET
CHAOS
MUX
DCN-MEAS
HMP
PRM
XNS-IDP
TRUNK-1
TRUNK-2
LEAF-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is: "what protocols **based on** the Internet Protocol don't use the notion of ports?" (emphasis mine).

So, the answer depends on what you mean by "based on" :-)

Any protocol that is encapsulated within IP is "based on" IP in the practical sense that it is being sent via IP.

If what you meant by "based on IP" is that the protocol shares an approach to protocol design that is similar to IP, then this would include any protocol that provides capabilities similar to IP, such as being connectionless and offering best-effort delivery.  In that case, take a look at ICMP and IGMP which are the two protocols that are classically associated with IP in the 'Internet layer' of the standard TCP/IP model.

Lastly, if I could perhaps offer you a piece of advice, considering reading the book *TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols* by [W. Richard Stevens](http://www.kohala.com/start/). That book will provide you with a very thorough, step-by-step understanding of the TCP/IP protocol suite.  (Be aware also that there are two editions of that book, and my understanding is that the first edition is generally preferred.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. By "based on IP", I actually meant, "using IP under the hood" or "relying on IP". I've updated the questions accordingly. And thanks for the link :)

Comment: No problem :-) It really is the best book on TCP/IP!